# How to plot date format in x-axis using Javascript and data from JSON

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I am trying to plot Concentration of CO2 vs Date from a JSON file that has this kind of date format:

For a point in the x-axis:

```
"ts": "2020-07-03T12:00:00.000Z",
```

and for a point in the y-axis

```
"co_sum": 424.5,
```

So I managed to plot it if I use "i" instead of date from an array, but I can't manage to plot the date using CanvasJS. How can one convert that data format into something that can be plotted on the x-axis. Basically, instead of *i*, some kind of date format.

```js
$.getJSON("somejsonsite.json", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {


    for (var i = 0; i - 1 < data.length; i++) {
      dataPoints1.push({
        x: i,
        y: data[i].co_sum
      });
    }
  });
  chart.render();

});
```

This is what I get now:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what date pattern you exactly want but here I have used whatever the value of `i` happens to be to offset the current datetime value by that many seconds

```
for (var i = 0; i - 1 < data.length; i++) {
  dataPoints1.push({
    x: new Date(Date.now()+ (i*1000)),
    y: data[i].co_sum
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**

So just change `x: new Date(Date.now()+ (i*1000)),` to `x: new Date(data[i].ts),`

The [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) will parse and convert to date object automatically

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ah, now it's getting closer. By using your code I could plot the time, which is a big step forward. However, I would like instead of getting the current data, to read the data that comes with every entry in the JSON. The date for each *co_sum* entry is labeled *ts* (which has the format from the OP), which has the date and the hour.